Fivebrane bordism $\Omega_d^{\mathrm{Fivebrane}}$
$\newcommand{\Fr}{\mathrm{Fr}}\newcommand{\Fivebrane}{\mathrm{Fivebrane}}\newcommand{\String}{\mathrm{String}}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$What are the (lower-dimensional, say $d \leq 14$) Fivebrane bordism groups
$$
\Omega_d^{\Fivebrane}=\text?
$$
Given that we know the Whitehead tower
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\vdots \\
@VVV \\
B\Fivebrane \\
@VVV \\
B\String @>\frac1 6 p_2>> B^7U(1) @>\cong>> B^8\mathbb Z \\
@VVV \\
B{\Spin} @>\frac1 2 p_1>> B^3U(1) @>\cong>> B^4\mathbb Z \\
@VVV \\
B{\SO} @>w_2>> B^2\mathbb Z_2 \\
@VVV \\
BO @>w_1>> B\mathbb Z_2 \\
@VV\cong V \\
B{\GL}
\end{CD}$$
and the string bordism groups:
\begin{align*}
& \Omega_0^{\String}=Z \\
& \Omega_1^{\String}=Z_2 \\
& \Omega_2^{\String}=Z_2 \\
& \Omega_3^{\String}=Z_{24} \\
& \Omega_4^{\String}=0 \\
& \Omega_5^{\String}=0 \\
& \Omega_6^{\String}=Z_2 \\
& \Omega_7^{\String}=0 \\
\end{align*}
Framed bordism:
$$\Omega_7^{\Fr}=Z_{240}.$$
Note that
$$
\Omega_d^{\String}=\Omega_d^{\Fr}, d \leq 6.
$$
Is it true that
$$
\Omega_d^{\Fivebrane}=\Omega_d^{\Fr}, d \leq 7?
$$
How about
$$
\Omega_d^{\Fivebrane}=\text?, \text{ for }  d > 7?
$$

This should be a comment but turns out too long...
According to Bott's periodicity, the next layer of your Whitehead tower is $\cdots\to \mathrm{MFivebrane}\to B^9\mathbb{Z}/2$. Hence your guess is true. Moreover, $\Omega^{\mathrm{fr}}_{8}\to\Omega^{\mathrm{Fivebrane}}_{8}$ is an epimorphism.
The reason is as follows.
Consider a stable tangential structure $S$ in your Whitehead tower.
Recall that the Thom spectrum $\mathbb{M}S$ is defined by the Thom spaces of the canonical vector bundle on $BS(n)$ and the natural embeddings.
Therefore, the connectedness of the natural spectrum map $\mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{M}S$ is determined by the connectedness of $BS$.
More precisely, $\mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{M}S$ is $(n\!-\!1)$-connected if $BS$ is $(n\!+\!1)$-connected.
This implies that $\Omega^{\mathrm{Fr}}_{\bullet}\equiv\mathbb{S}_{\bullet}\to\Omega^{S}_{\bullet}\equiv\mathbb{M}S_{\bullet}$ is an isomorphism for $\bullet\leq n$ and is an epimorphism for $\bullet=n\!+\!1$.

As for the general structure of $\Omega^{\mathrm{Fivebrane}}_{\bullet}$, I'm not aware of a computation in the literature.
I'm also interested in knowing about it.

May I ask if there's a difference between $\Omega^{\mathrm{Fr}}$ and $\Omega^{\mathrm{fr}}$ (some kind of connectivity?) or was that inadvertent?

@DavidRoberts They are the same. Sorry for being careless.

not a problem! I edited to make them the same, but then I know there's a big difference between eg Tmf and tmf,  so I made sure I didn't submit that change.
